# Что делать с незавершенными Task-ами при закрытии приложения?

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть список задач которые были запущенны при старте приложения и каждая из них не будет выполняется на фоне в бесконечном цикле. все задачи я храню в списке

```
public List<Task> BackGroundTask
```

Когда я закрываю положение что делать с этими задачами например в обработчике

```
FormClosing()
```

Посмотрел в отладчике, статус всех задач на момент закрытия окна
TaskStatus = WaitingForActivation. Может надо передавать CancellationToken во все задачи и в FormClosing() вызывать Cancel() у CancellationToken? Инфраструктура с токеном присутствует. Но хотелось бы узнать еще варианты?

Comment: У CanselationToken нет метода Clouse(). Вместо этого у Can***c***elationTokenSource есть метод Cancel()

Comment: Прежде всего вы должны спросить _себя_, что именно вам нужно сделать пл смыслу вашей программы: дождаться окончания все тасков, или оборвать их?

Comment: CancelationTokenSource есть метод Cancel() - все верно я сам не правильно написал. я думаю что дождаться я их не смогу там бесконечный цикл опроса и только не обработанный Exception их прервет. Я думаю при закрытии приложения можно просто их обрывать. там основная блокировка это ожидание ответа по TcpIp 6 клиентов и по SerialPort - 6 slave устройств. Никакой работы с БД в этом слое нету или других критических секций кода.

Comment: Ребят где все???

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален

Comment: В итоге я протащил CanselationToken. и в событии FormClosing() вызываю Cancel(). в итоге все задачи останавливаются.

Answer (score 1):

В идеале во все задачи нужно передавать `CancellationToken`, чтобы у них была возможность "узнать" об отмене. Каждая задача может останавливаться либо "мягко", проверяя свойство `IsCancellationRequested` токена, либо "жестко", вызывая метод `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

При завершении приложения вызываете отмену у соответствующего `CancellationTokenSource` и ожидаете (`await`) все задачи, чтобы отловить возможные исключения, и пишете исключения в логи. Обратите внимание, что если какие-то задачи завершаются "жестко", то нужно иметь отдельный блок `catch (OperationCanceledException e) where e.CancellationToken == source.Token`, чтобы отфильтровывать такие задачи (они хоть и завершились с исключением, но это признак их "жесткого" завершения).

На практике же ответ на вопрос больше зависит от ваших требований :).

Comment: @Etki зря поправили, все правильно было написано. Речь о запускаемых задачах.

Comment: Тут как ни крути невозможен родительный падеж. И в любом случае проверочный вопрос будет "в чём?" - в задаче.

Comment: @Etki речь о запускаемЫХ задачАХ. Множественное число.

Comment: ох, втупил, каюсь